# Height of a d-ary heap of n-elements in terms of n and d

Tags: algorithm, heap

I worked on this problem via the following approach:-

1. n <= 1+d+d<sup>2</sup>+…….+d<sup>h</sup>
2. n >= 1+d+d<sup>2</sup>+……..+d<sup>h-1</sup>+1

These two equations led me to the following range of h:-

log<sub>d</sub>((n(d-1)+1)/2) <= h <= log<sub>d</sub>((n-1)(d-1)+1)

But I can’t figure out how to further deduce from this inequality so that h = big-theta(log<sub>d</sub>n)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more Mathematically correct solution has been provided to my question in math.stackexchange.com.
Please refer to the link below to look at the proof:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2318306/height-of-a-d-ary-heap-of-n-elements-in-terms-of-n-and-d

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The number of items in a full d-heap of n levels is (1-d<sup>n</sup>)/(1-d). A seven level binary heap contains 127 items. A seven-level 4-heap would contain 5,461 (16383/3) items.

A  little algebra tells us that the number of levels required to hold n items in a d-heap is log<sub>d</sub>(n*(d - 1) + 1). So a 4-heap with 21 items takes log<sub>4</sub>(20*(4 - 1)+1), or 2.96 levels. We can’t have a partial level, so we round up to 3.

See my blog post, [The d-ary heap](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/10/05/the-d-ary-heap/), for more details.